# Download github release by url is giving 404 not found

Tags: git, http, github, header, authorization

I'm trying to download a private repository release using the browser_download_url that I got from the github API, but the URL is giving me 404 Not Found, I set up the Authentication : token <my_token> correctly but I'm still getting 404.

The repository it's from my organization and I'm using a read_only service account for the repo if it's of use.

[Here is a postman image with my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcyuv.png)

Using my browser I can download the file just fine.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to use the `browser_download_url` field.  That endpoint is designed to handle users in a browser with a session cookie set, and your API request is not going to be configured correctly.  For security reasons, the endpoints that handle user requests with cookies and those that handle programmatic requests are generally different and use different authentication.

To download the release asset, use the `url` field instead, which goes through the API and should handle things appropriately.  Your token will need to have the appropriate scope (which I *believe* is `repo`) and, if your organization is using SSO, be enabled for SSO, and you'll also need to set the `Accept` header to `application/octet-stream` (which it looks like you're already doing) and handle any redirects that occur.

Comment: I used the asset url but the only thing I'm getting is the information of the release not the actual .zip file

Comment: Your `Accept` header is wrong, according to [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset).

Comment: The header is se as application/octet-stream, which the docs says exactly that, what do you mean by is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was the actual token. The Github API returns 404 if the authentication fails even if the resource exists (in order to not leak information)

My issue was that I thought a token with `read` access would be enough. However, to download a release, you need `write` access too.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having these problem, my solution was to add application/octet-stream header from the programing languague that I was using (Python) for some reason it will not work from postman, you will get a invalid media type header.

Comment: Adding the application/octet-stream to my Postman config let me download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just hitting same problem as well, i do have my PAT token with full granted acecess, then i'm trying to downlad json from here [latest.json](https://github.com/AndonMitev/tauri-updater-private-repo/releases/latest/download/latest.json)

but hitting 404 all the time do have:

```
Accept: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Bearer {PAT}
```

but not sure what might be wrong, also tried with:

```
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
```

still 404

Answer (score 0):

Struggled a bit with this for downloading the bits from the github, As bk2204 mentioned above `browser_download_url` is specifically for browser downloads which uses session cookies. I want to download the tagged binaries from github via apis but didnt find any straight fwd way. Below are the commands i used which solved my purpose

```
FILE="<file name>"
REPO="<ORG/REPO>"
GITHUB_TOKEN="<github pat token>"
url="https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases"

# Get specific asset id
asset_id=`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" $url | jq ".[0].assets | map(select(.name == \"$FILE\"))[0] | .id"`

# Download the asset id with token
wget -q --auth-no-challenge --header='Accept:application/octet-stream' https://$GITHUB_TOKEN:@api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases/assets/$asset_id  -O $FILE
```

you can further filter out the specific tag version in jq parsing. here i am using the latest one with the index 0.